Restructure data using Ansible
I am trying to use the set_fact module to create a new variable based on data from another variable. I have tried the groupby and lists_mergeby filters with no success.
How can I, from this list:
"myVms": [
        {
            "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
            "VirtualMachine": "K606WS625"
        },
        {
            "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
            "VirtualMachine": "K606WS626"
        },
        {
            "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
            "VirtualMachine": "K606WS812"
        },
        {
            "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
            "VirtualMachine": "K606WS817"
        }
]

Turn it into a new list with a structure like the following?
"myVmsModified": [
    {
        "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
        "MyBeautifulVms": [
            "K606WS817",
            "K606WS812",
            "K606WS626",
            "K606WS625"
        ]
    }
]


The filter lists_mergeby can append lists. Convert the attributes VirtualMachine to lists
 myVmsModified: "{{ myVms | json_query('[].{SubscriptionId: SubscriptionId,
                                            VirtualMachine: [VirtualMachine]}') }}"

gives
  myVmsModified:
    - SubscriptionId: 564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c
      VirtualMachine: [K606WS625]
    - SubscriptionId: 564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c
      VirtualMachine: [K606WS626]
    - SubscriptionId: 564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c
      VirtualMachine: [K606WS812]
    - SubscriptionId: 564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c
      VirtualMachine: [K606WS817]

The filter is designed to merge two or more lists. If you want to merge items in a single list merge it into an empty list
  myVmsModified: "{{ [myVms | json_query('[].{SubscriptionId: SubscriptionId,
                                              VirtualMachine: [VirtualMachine]}'), []] |
                     community.general.lists_mergeby('SubscriptionId', list_merge='append') }}"

gives what you want
  myVmsModified:
    - SubscriptionId: 564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c
      VirtualMachine: [K606WS625, K606WS626, K606WS812, K606WS817]




Example of a complete playbook for testing

- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    myVms:
      - {SubscriptionId: 564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c, VirtualMachine: K606WS625}
      - {SubscriptionId: 564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c, VirtualMachine: K606WS626}
      - {SubscriptionId: 564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c, VirtualMachine: K606WS812}
      - {SubscriptionId: 564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c, VirtualMachine: K606WS817}

    myVmsModified: "{{ myVms | json_query('[].{SubscriptionId: SubscriptionId,
                                               VirtualMachine: [VirtualMachine]}') }}"
    myVmsModifie2: "{{ [myVms | json_query('[].{SubscriptionId: SubscriptionId,
                                                VirtualMachine: [VirtualMachine]}'), []] |
                       community.general.lists_mergeby('SubscriptionId', list_merge='append') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: myVmsModified | to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: myVmsModifie2 | to_yaml


Replace the attribute(s) if you want to

  target:
    - before: 'VirtualMachine'
      after: 'MyBeautifulVms'
  myVmsModified: "{{ [myVms | json_query('[].{SubscriptionId: SubscriptionId,
                                              VirtualMachine: [VirtualMachine]}'), []] |
                     community.general.lists_mergeby('SubscriptionId', list_merge='append') |
                     community.general.replace_keys(target=target) }}"



Thanks for your answer. I tried this suggestion, but the VirtualMachine key became a list of lists containing strings.

Looks like I was too quick trying out your suggestion. It worked! I initially combined your two suggestions into 1, and the result became like I/you described.

Here's one possible way. Note that this solution uses groupby but as you can see it needs a bit of rework. But you were probably on the good track. You can debug the intermediate variables to study the solution.
Side note: I used the ansible naming convention for my vars but you can switch to camel case for your data if this is needed for your project
The following playbook:
---
- name: Transform data
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    # Original variable
    "my_vms": [
        {
            "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
            "VirtualMachine": "K606WS625"
        },
        {
            "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
            "VirtualMachine": "K606WS626"
        },
        {
            "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
            "VirtualMachine": "K606WS812"
        },
        {
            "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
            "VirtualMachine": "K606WS817"
        }
    ]

    # Group original var by subscription id
    _raw_grouped_vms: "{{ my_vms | groupby('SubscriptionId') }}"

    # List of subscription ids
    _subscription_ids: "{{ _raw_grouped_vms | map(attribute=0) }}"

    # List of lists of vms for each subscription id (in the same order)
    _vms_by_id: "{{ _raw_grouped_vms | map(attribute=1) | map('map', attribute='VirtualMachine') }}"

    # Create a dict with key=<subscription id> and value=<list of vms>
    my_vms_modified_dict: "{{ dict(_subscription_ids | zip(_vms_by_id)) }}"

    # Transform that dict to a list of dicts as expected
    my_vms_modified_list: "{{ my_vms_modified_dict | dict2items(key_name='subscription_id', value_name='my_beautiful_vms') }}"


  tasks:
    - name: Show expected result
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: my_vms_modified_list

gives:
PLAY [Transform data] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show expected result] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_vms_modified_list": [
        {
            "my_beautiful_vms": [
                "K606WS625",
                "K606WS626",
                "K606WS812",
                "K606WS817"
            ],
            "subscription_id": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0 


Thank you Zeitounator. Looks like it failed while creating the dictionary. Got error: "Unable to look up a name or access an attribute".

Ansible isn't great at data manipulation. While it may be possible to do what you want with a combination of Ansible filters, it almost all cases it easier just to write a custom filter in Python. Drop the following into filter_plugins/myfilters.py:
import itertools


def pivot_on_subscriptionid(v):
    return [
        {
            "SubscriptionId": key,
            "MyBeautifulVms": [vm["VirtualMachine"] for vm in grp],
        }
        for key, grp in itertools.groupby(
            sorted(v, key=lambda x: x["SubscriptionId"]),
            key=lambda x: x["SubscriptionId"],
        )
    ]


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {
            "pivot_on_subscriptionid": pivot_on_subscriptionid,
        }

Now you can write a playbook like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    maxuid: 500
    myVms: [
            {
                "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
                "VirtualMachine": "K606WS625"
            },
            {
                "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
                "VirtualMachine": "K606WS626"
            },
            {
                "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
                "VirtualMachine": "K606WS812"
            },
            {
                "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c",
                "VirtualMachine": "K606WS817"
            }
    ]
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        new_vm_list: "{{ myVms | pivot_on_subscriptionid }}"

    - debug:
        var: new_vm_list

And get this output:
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "new_vm_list": [
        {
            "MyBeautifulVms": [
                "K606WS625",
                "K606WS626",
                "K606WS812",
                "K606WS817"
            ],
            "SubscriptionId": "564aba40-77683-4426-84ac-d195769c826c"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


